# Customize syntax highlightin in canopy

Tags: syntax-highlighting, enthought, canopy

I just installed Enthought Canopy in a freshly (clean) installed Mac OS X Mountain Lion. So far, it seems to run stable and fast. My only problem is that I want to customize the syntax highlighting of both the editor and the console. There are no preferences to allow for that what I find quite strange because the embedded editor is just Editra, a highly customizable editor. I want to:

- Editor. As I was using Editra before, where can I place my old style file (.ess) for the syntax highlighting such that it will overwrite the default one?
- Interactive window. How do I dissable the syntax highlighting from the interactive window? I tried the magic function "%colors nocolor" but this makes nothing. I saw there is a monochrome theme for the editor, but I want a Dark brackground with no syntax highlighting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you're finding Canopy useful.

Neither of these options is supported at this time. Canopy is designed to be an easy-to-learn environment, with relatively few configuration options, primarily for scientists, engineers, and analysts, rather than for professional developers who usually already have an editor of choice. We will slowly add features when there is a strong demand and/or use-case for it.

FWIW, Canopy does not embed Editra, though it does use the same syntax highlighting toolkit as does Editra (Pygments).

Comment: Thanks. I guess that for the moment I will stick to coding the old fashion: editor + ipython on terminal.

I love the idea of Canopy, to finally have an integrated environment for scientific computing in python that can compete face-to-face with other well-known software. But (just my opinion) if you want Canopy to be a success you can't wait for noobies to come and give it a try. There are millions of scientists and engineers already using python and EDP. Make them love Canopy and it will get an enormous momentum. Call it "rich-gets-richer" or "preferential attachment".

All the best.

Comment: Another scientist here wishing to change the editor color theme. Almost all IDEs include this. It doesn't have to be full customization but there should be a few good options, just like there already are for the interactive window.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer is.... Not Yet.
I usually insert a lot of comments into my python code, and COLOR ALL #COMMENTS LIGHT GRAY, so they are not so distracting from the main logic, but have been unable to do that in Enthought Canopy. Too bad. Hopefully this ability will be added soon.

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to provide any information that isn't already covered in the other answer. It really should have been a comment.