# how to configure canopy's editor to use dark-background colorschemes

Tags: editor, enthought, canopy

Is there any way of setting the colorscheme for Canopy's editor window? I have one already on ~/.ipython/profile_default/, but Canopy does not seem to care about these settings... Any help would be highly appreciated.

cheers
Rodrigo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526556/customize-syntax-highlightin-in-canopy